# Twilio SMS message Not Delivered with unknown error

Tags: sms, twilio

We're having this weird problem with Twilio SMS messages hanging with status.

We have tried sending from different Twilio phone numbers to make sure it isn't a problem with that particular number being blocked and none of them go through.

Our system uses SMS messages in the standard form of two-step authentication with a code and a short message to the user inside the SMS body.

The carrier that the message sent is failing is Tune Talk (A Malaysian one).

The error in the Twilio Logs/Console I see is:

```
Status: Undelivered
Error: (Error: 30008) Unknown error. None
```

Message SID if it's in any way useful is: SM1024a2d519cf4f6bbfcbc838587cb2af

Any insight on why this is happening would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

We had also the same issue with phones that used to receive messages.
The problem is carrier blocking/filtering.
Every carrier uses different filters.

Some carriers block messages with 90% the same content, others use rate filtering (1 message per second or more) others use a combination. The blocking is not forever thought.

Twilio gives the following possible solutions:

Check that the phone you were sending to is turned on and can receive SMS

1. Ensure that the phone is not roaming off network. We cannot
   guarantee message delivery on roaming phones.
2. Try sending to other phones who have the same mobile carrier.
   If messages to other phones go through, the issue is likely device
   related. Try rebooting the device or contact the mobile carrier for
   help.
3. If you are sending SMS from an alphanumeric sender ID, see if using
   a Twilio phone number works better. We’ve observed that certain
   networks may block alpha sender IDs.
4. Try sending a shorter message to the phone, with simple content that
   does not include any special characters. This would give our support
   team an idea as to whether the failure is related to concatenation
   or character encoding.
5. Twilio support can help investigate what went
   wrong with our carriers. Please open a support request and include a
   minimum of 3 or more message `SIDs` where a `30008 error` was thrown.
   Per our carriers' requirements, these `SIDs` can be no older than 48
   hours at most.

[Check -> Error 30008](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30008)

Another solution is to use a 5digit code phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Boris, [error 30008](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30008) is certainly less descriptive than one would hope. In this case, it would be best to send that Message Sid along to [support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) where we can dig a little deeper into the specifics.

Though it doesn't sound like it in this case, if there were a problem with your code, you could check out a production ready [account verification tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/php/laravel) here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info, I'll contact them ASAP.

Yeah I guess it's a very edge-casey type of issue, since 99% of our SMS messages are going through perfectly fine, but we seem to be having a problem with this particular carrier.

Answer (score 1):

Came here because of exactly the same problem.  I have someone who successfully received SMSes just 12 days ago, using the same Australian number, getting a 30008 for every attempt to send to them today.  That's a really average-quality error message right there.

The user states that they ported the number from Telstra to Vodafone, but that was 3 months ago.  I'm guessing that the forwarding is broken:

http://www.commsalliance.com.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0013/2326/G565_2009.pdf

In particular:

1.4.4 Where internationally originated SMS is supported donor routing
must be supported wherever bilateral agreement exists for the
national leg, as international networks are not likely to access an
Australian mobile number portability database prior to routing the
message. However, certain limitations apply – see Appendix A.

Since Twilio aren't sending from an Australian number, they probably aren't looking through the number portability database.  This would be my suspect cause for any failure to SMS route to a country with number portability.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some of these errors when doing MMS's.

If I look at the detail in the Twilio console, there is additional detail and a secondary error message "12300 Invalid Content-Type. Attempt to retrieve MediaUrl returned an unsupported Content-Type."

I was putting images up on S3, but not setting the Content-Type of the image when I put it on S3.

Comment: Also make sure that the image file is actually of the type of the Content-Type that you set. i.e. if you set Content-Type of image/jpeg and the file has extension .jpeg but the bits of the file have PNG at the start... well, then Twilio will give the 12300 Invalid Content-Type error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was including a website **URL** in the message.

Once I removed it (replaced it with a simple name) it worked.

I'm not sure whether the issue was the URL itself (e.g. the network considers it spam) or the fact that it contained characters like `/`.